# Get back a numpy array from JPEG encoded (by cv2.imencode) bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, encoding, opencv

I'm sending an image from a grpc client as bytes.

In the client,

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('a.jpg')
img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1] # memory buffer, type returns <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

# encode as bytes object, so I can send
img_bytes = bytearray(img_encoded) # type bytes
```

How can I reverse the process to get the image as a numpy array in the server end?

I can use imdecode but how to reverse the bytearray function? `img_bytes.decode()` fails with UnicodeDecodeError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here it is:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('a.jpg')
img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tobytes()  # bytes class

# 'repair' image from byte array
nparr = np.frombuffer(img_encoded, np.byte)
img2 = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
```